# How do I compare numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have got this script, but it is not working. It is because it is failing to evaluate the number comparison in the if statement, I think.

```
#!/bin/bash

{ read __ WIDTH; read __ HEIGHT; read __ __ BORDER_WIDTH; } < <(xwininfo -id "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" | grep -o -e 'Height:.*' -e 'Width:.*' -e 'Border width:.*')
echo "Height: $HEIGHT, Width: $WIDTH, Border width: $BORDER_WIDTH"

x = 1920
if($WIDTH == x)
then
    wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz 
else 
    xdotool key Ctrl+F12
fi
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use proper numeric comparisons - `-eq` for equal, etc.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several issues with the script:

- `bash` tests are either done with `test`, `[ .. ]` or `[[ .. ]]`; `(` .. `)` means sub-shell
- Assignment are made without spaces, `x = 1920` will call the command `x` with the parameters `=` and `1920`. Use `x=1920` instead.
- Variable names need to be prefixed with a dollar sign when you use them. So `== x` is bad and `== $x` is good. (Except within arithmetic evaluations or expansions: `(( ... ))` or `$(( ... ))`, thanks to comment by [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)).
- Numbers should be compared with `-eq`, `=` is for string comparison. In your case it should also work since the numbers are likely to be stored identically, but it's better to use the conceptually correct operator. `==` is a non-standard equivalent to `=`.
- You should get used to double quoting variables everywhere when possible, which prevents globbing for instance.

I'll just fix the lines starting from `x = 1920`, the fixed version is:

```
x=1920
if [ "$WIDTH" -eq "$x" ]
then
    wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz 
else 
    xdotool key Ctrl+F12
fi
```

Comment: About your third point: Except within arithmetic evaluations or expansions: `(( ... ))` or `$(( ... ))`.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers noted, `(...)` indicates subshell. Arithmetic expansion is `((...))`, so in case of `bash` you should be using `((...))` or `[[`, or POSIXly `[`. The `((` can be used as so:

```
$ if ((1==1)); then echo "YES" ;fi
YES
```

Note, however, that in case of `[[`, the `==` operator indicates pattern matching, i.e. it is not arithmetic comparison.

Alternatively, if you really want to use `==` operator with POSIX shell, one could do the following:

```
$ foo=1
$ bar=2
$ if [ $((foo==bar)) -eq 1 ]; then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi
NO
$ bar=1
$ if [ $((foo==bar)) -eq 1 ]; then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi
YES
```

In case of POSIX shell `/bin/sh` there's no `((` operator, however there is `$((`, which expands to the result of an arithmetic expression. Comparison operators within it act in a C-like manner, where 1 indicates a true result, and 0 indicates a false result (as opposed to usual shell way, where 0 is success and non-zero is failure).

Answer (score 1):

`if(a == b)` is not the proper syntax for an integer comparison  Additionally, you invoke `x` without indicating it to be a variable, so you are (trying to) compare the value of `$WIDTH` with the literal string `x`.  Try instead:

```
if [[ $WIDTH -eq $x ]]
```

Comment: Quote your variable. The assignment to `x` is just as buggy.

Comment: When I quote variables in `[[ [...] ]]` constructs, I get told I don't have to.  When I don't, I get told I should.  I cannot win.

Comment: -1 | For you have used `[[ .. ]]` when not necessary. Ordinary test command should be used in such a case.

Comment: @Vlastimil whatever for? This is a bash script. There's no reason to use `[` at all.

Comment: If you're using `bash`, there is literally no reason ever to use the `[ [...] ]` construct which is both a subset and more prone to failure due to PICNIC issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
# use xrandr+sed to get current screen width
screenWidth=`xrandr|sed -En '/connected [0-9]+x[0-9]+/{s/^.*connected ([0-9]+)x[0-9]+.*$/\1/;p}'`

# use xdotool getwindowgeometry --shell to get size/pos of window
eval `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry --shell`

echo $screenWidth $WIDTH # debug, to see values got from xrandr and xdotool

if [[ $WIDTH = $screenWidth ]]; then
  wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz 
else 
  xdotool key Ctrl+F12
fi
```

Explanation:

1. In `bash`, do not put space(s) arround `=` when assigning values; example `x=123`, not `x = 123`.
2. To compare things in `bash`, use `[[ .. ]]`.
3. `xdotool` already has `getwindowgeometry --shell` for `bash` programming.

Comment: -1 | For you have used `eval` and `\`` unnecessarilly