# shell script crashes during if statements?

Tags: shell

```
for hi in `seq 0 100`
do
    new_val=1
    if `expr $hi % 5` -eq 5
    then
        echo hello
    elif `expr $hi % 5` -eq 6
    then
        echo bye
    elif `expr $hi % 5` -eq 7
    then
        echo whats up
    fi
    echo $new_val
done
```

Why does this crash? The goal is to check if the loop number module 5 equals 5,6, or 7.

Comment: Doesn't crash here with bash. Are you using sh?

Comment: yes sh is what im using

Comment: I shall assume that what you meant with `if \`expr $hi % 5\` -eq 5` is actually `if [ $(expr $hi % 5) -eq 5 ]` (note the [ ] added). You have three elements with this problem.

Comment: None of the if will be true if the math operation is a modulus because the modulus of 5 can never be 5, 6 or 7. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare numbers in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420768/how-do-i-compare-numbers-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script corrected shall be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh 

for hi in $(seq 0 100)
do
    if [ "$(expr $hi % 5)" -eq 5 ]
    then
        echo hello
    elif [ "$(expr $hi % 5)" -eq 6 ]
    then
        echo bye
    elif [ "$(expr $hi % 5)" -eq 7 ]
    then
        echo whats up
    fi
    echo "$hi"
done
```

But that loop will never enter any of the ifs as the remainder of a modulus 5 operation will never be 5, 6 or 7.